# Possible to add template file to component on plugin installation?

Tags: plugin, templates, custom-component

I am making a plugin for a custom component. It's a basic editor extend plugin that allows users to select an item from custom component using a button in editor. It's simular to native editor extend buttons to add link to article, menu and contact items.

To do this, I need to add a `modal.php` file to my components view tmpl folder. Should I update the component to add the new tmpl file? Or is it possible to add the file on plugin installation?

Comment: If it's your custom component, add the file on component installation/update process. Yes, it's possible to perform any operation on plugin install as well, including copying files where you need. Check for example (it works the same for any extension): 
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file

Comment: Thanks @AHeavyObject I will check that out.